# Question about two polynomials having the same value over an interval

Tags: polynomials

Say you have a polynomial `p1` of degree `n` and a polynomial `p2` of degree `m`, where `n<m` and belong to the Natural Numbers. Is there an interval `I` (belonging to the Real Numbers) that exists where `p1(x)=p2(x)` for all values of `x` in `I`?

I understand Math only at the undergraduate level :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If two polynomials agree on an inteval $[a,b]$ with $a \neq b$ then they agree everywhere and are the same polynomial.

Comment: Given two different polynomials (degrees could be the same or different), their difference is a nonzero polynomial, and since nonzero polynomials have at most a finite number of roots, the difference can only be zero for finitely many (domain) values, hence the two original polynomials can only agree for finitely many (domain) values.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro do you have something i can look at on this? or like a key word to google?

Comment: @OctaveParango See [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)

Comment: @Golden_Ratio mentioned the fundamental theorem of algebra, but you don't actually need this, which is surprisingly hard to prove compared to what follows. You only need: If $r$ is a (real) root, then $x-r$ is a factor. This is sometimes called the "factor theorem" and it's a special case of the "remainder theorem", both of which are proved in most college algebra and precalculus texts (so their proofs are not difficult, and their proofs do not involve advanced topics). From this it's fairly straightforward to show that an $n$th degree polynomial cannot have more than $n$ many real roots.